# Unbounded solutions and orbits to an second order non linear differential equation

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

This question is two folded.

Question 1:  I want to find out whatever or not the equation $y''(t)=4y(t)-4y(t)^3$ have an unbounded solution.

I can write it as $y''(t)=4y(t)(1-y(t)^2)$. Clearly $0$ is a solution. Also I can c not solve this, since its a second order non-linear equation. Any ideas on how to approach the problem?

Question 2: I want to find an orbit that passes through the point (1,1) of the equation

$y''(t)=4y(t)-6y(t)^2$

I know how to do this for any system of equations, and since this is not linear I can not reduce it to such a system.

Comment: To solve the problem for $y$, multiply through by $y'$ and integrate to get $$(y')^{2}/2 = 2y^{2} - y^{4}$$ Then take the square root. Your ODE is then separable and can be integrated again using a trig substitution.

Comment: @Mattos: There is an integration constant missing, which may make integration a little more difficult.

Comment: @LutzL You're right, I missed that. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can establish a first integral or energy function
$$
H(y,v)=\frac12v^2+(y^2-1)^2
$$
so that for all solutions $H(y(t),y'(t))\equiv const.$

This should give all answers re bounded/unbounded solutions.

---

As to the second equation, again finding the first integral via multiplication with $y'$ and integration is possible and gives
$$
\frac12 y'^2=2y^2-2y^3+C
$$
and the initial conditions amount to $C=\frac12$.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little on how to get the function $H$ and what $v$ is?

Comment: Multiply the DE with $y'$ and integrate. Be inventive with the integration constant. $v$ obviously stands for velocity, or the first derivative. (Usual mix-up corrected.)

Comment: Just a comment to what you just added for my secodn question. The point (1,1) does that not correspond to $y(1)=1$? you seem to use it as $y=y'=1$. Also an orbit for a 2 dim. system is given by (x(t),y(t)), thus for a 1 dimension case, such as this, the orbit is (y(t)) which is just the solution?

Comment: For a scalar order 2 ODE, the phase space is 2 dimensional. As it is autonomous, the initial time is irrelevant, thus if not explicitly given it can always assumed to be $0$. Thus the solution passing through the point $(1,1)$ means that the curve can be obtained as solution to the IVP $(y(0),y'(0))=(1,1)$.